# Does UILabel have a horizontal padding?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

Does UILabel have a horizontal padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it inherits from UIView, so check out if you can achieve what you want with Frame and Bounds http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView

Comment: I have some horizontal padding, I have set the label.layer.opaque=NO; and it solved the problem. :)